# XML Resonspe need to display in table format using php

Tags: php, xml, soap

```
$response = $client->ApiCallDeatilDataFeed($params);
print_r($response);
```

this is the output :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ApiCallDeatilDataFeedResult] => <ApidsfsdfCustomerReport>
  <status>Success</status>
  <report_creation_time>9/23/2022 11:27:40 PM</report_creation_time>
  <tru_id>234244234</tru_id>
  <report_date startdate="9/13/2012" enddate="9/14/2012" />
  <call_data row="1">
    <call_tracking_number>2324234324234</call_tracking_number>
    <call_time>9/13/2012 3:33:46 PM</call_time>
    <call_duration>128</call_duration>
    <call_status>Answered</call_status>
    <caller_number>43434543242</caller_number>
    <caller_name></caller_name>
    <caller_address>SAN JOSE CA 95117</caller_address>
    <caller_city>SAN JOSE</caller_city>
    <caller_state>CA</caller_state>
    <caller_zip>95117</caller_zip>
    <call_record_url></call_record_url>
  </call_data>

</ApiCustomerReport>
)
```

while using soap methos am receiving above following output i need to display this format into html table format

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward job. What issues are you facing. Have you written any code and came up against a wall? If so, please share your code.

Comment: i need to print the output as table format instead of xml response

Comment: i have posted the response. Please select this is the answer if this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`$response` is the php object you dumped in your question.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Call Tracking Number</th>
                <th>Call Time</th>
                <th>Call Duration</th>
                <th>Call Status</th>
                <th>Caller Number</th>
                <th>Caller Name</th>
                <th>Caller Address</th>
                <th>Caller City</th>
                <th>Caller State</th>
                <th>Caller Zip</th>
                <th>Call Record Url</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $xml = simplexml_load_string( $response->ApiCallDeatilDataFeedResult );
            foreach ( $xml->call_data as $data )
            {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data->call_tracking_number;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->call_time;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->call_duration;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->call_status;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->caller_number;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->caller_name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->caller_address;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->caller_city;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->caller_state;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->caller_zip;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->call_record_url;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\xampp\htdocs\finance\trumeasure\call.php on line 19

Comment: What does `$obj->ApiCallDeatilDataFeedResult` give?

Comment: nothing only i got error msg above. here is the input coding . $client = new SoapClient("http://yourdomain.com.asmx?WSDL");
$params->requestXML = " 
<ApiReportingRequest>
<action>calldetailfeed</action>
<api_token>8RBDC7D08-D9A3E-493F3-ABBF1-C1F7A94524A2</api_token>
<partner_id>114</partner_id>
<true_id>9366</true_id>
</ApiReportingRequest>
";
$response = $client->ApiCallDeatilDataFeed($params);

Comment: Please correct your `XML` response in the object first. The ending/closing tags do not match. Change `<ApidsfsdfCustomerReport>` to `<ApiCustomerReport>`, then it will work.

Comment: Can you post your response here. Also, check if the XML returned is properly formatted. The one you have posted here is not a valid xml.

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [ApiCallDeatilDataFeedResult] => <TruApiCustomerReport>
  <status>Success</status>
  <report_creation_time>9/16/2012 11:27:40 PM</report_creation_time>
  <tru_id>924366</tru_id>
  <report_date startdate="9/13/2012" enddate="9/14/2012" />
  <call_data row="1">
     <caller_address>SAN JOSE CA 95117</caller_address>
    <caller_city>SAN JOSE</caller_city>
    <caller_state>CA</caller_state>
    <caller_zip>95117</caller_zip>
    <call_record_url></call_record_url>
  </call_data>
</TruApiCustomerReport>
)

Comment: this is the response am receiving while request the api

Comment: ...and what is this variable called? I've have assumed it to be `$obj`. Change it to whatever the name of your variable is. Also, note that all variables are not present in your xml as compared to your original xml in the question.

Comment: Glad i could help. Please select this as the correct answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_string( $response->ApiCallDeatilDataFeedResult );
  i selected this answer is correct. pls change the line. so it will usefull to others